# wp_list_pages with featured image (as background)

Tags: background-image, wordpress

i'm using the wp_list_pages function to list all pages, and their children nested within.

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&exclude=17' ); ?>
```

but some of the pages have featured images assigend, which need to be displayed as the background-image of the page-item-container.

i already found a solution to display the images, but they where always contained in a img-tag.

i guess i need a custom loop — but i have no idea how set it up.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us a solution that you found so it can be helpful.

Comment: To learn the WordPress LOOP .. go to the WordPress Codex and see `The_Loop`: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop .. that will show you how to do loops of posts and pages the WordPress way.